# What is the meaning of '$' sign in react js

Tags: reactjs

I was using the '$' in my program but don't know the exact meaning of it.

For example: `input_${props.id}`

Comment: It just represents a variable in [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is Template literals

it use for provide an easy way to interpolate variables and expressions into strings.

you can get more detail here

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-template-literals/
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp
- https://www.javatpoint.com/es6-template-literals